# Converting date to readable format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to convert a date format in my dataset to something readable by R. My idea was to use the strftime function:

```
time = strftime("Tue Jan 01 19:28:39 EST 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

But it resulted in the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How might I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.POSIXct` instead:

```
time = as.POSIXct("Tue Jan 01 19:28:39 EST 2013", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y")
```

The same `format` mask should technically work with `strftime` as well, but did not work on my system. YMMV.

Comment: But it is not the use of `as.POSIXct` that makes this work: it is the correct format string with both a year (required) and the fudge of inserting EST as the timezone is often a spot of bother on input.  In short, with the correct format string, `as.POSIXlt` works the same way (as does `strptime`).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yeah, I was pretty sure that with the right format `strftime` should also work, but I was getting an error on my system with the same mask with `strftime`. I will reword the answer but cannot verify the `strftime` issue.

Comment: Sorry,  meant strptime.

Answer (score 0):

ParsedDate <- strptime("Tue Jan 01 19:28:39 EST 2013" ,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EST %Y")