# How you convert a character date (February 12, 1931) to date format (Y,m,d)

Tags: r

I'm having a problem converting a data frame column from whatever format it read the txt file as to a date format.

```
movie_df <- read.csv("scary_movies.txt",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     na.strings = c("NA", ""),
                     sep = "\t")
```

This is how we read the file.

There's a column called ReleaseDate that has the date in this format: February 12, 1931. How could I change it to 1931/2/12.

If I use strptime() the column shows up as NA.

Comment: Not familar with R. See if either these two links help - [a](https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/r-programming/how-to-convert-string-to-date-in-r-programming-using-as-date-function) and [b](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting date to readable format in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898264/converting-date-to-readable-format-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to convert to `Date` class with `as.Date` and `format` it to the required format

```
movie_df$ReleaseDate <- format(as.Date(movie_df$ReleaseDate,
        "%B %d, %Y"), '%Y/%m/%d')
```

with a reproducible example

```
format(as.Date('February 12, 1931', "%B %d, %Y"), '%Y/%m/%d')
#[1] "1931/02/12"
```

If the leading 0's for days/months needs to be dropped

```
sub("^(\\d{4})-0?(\\d{1,2})-0?(\\d{1,2})$", "\\1/\\2/\\3", 
       as.Date('February 12, 1931', "%B %d, %Y"))
#[1] "1931/2/12"
```